# What are the every possible sums of these numbers?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, combinations

Let $S=\{\pm a,\pm(a+b)\}$. If we take the sum of arbitrary $2$ elements of $S$, including duplication, the every possible sums are $\{0,b,2a+b,2a,2(a+b),-b,-(2a+b),-2a,-2(a+b)\}$.
Now, if $S=\{\pm a,\pm(a+b),\pm(a+2b)\}$, and if we take the sum of arbitrary $m$ elements of $S$, including duplication, how can we express the every possible sums?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $a$'s can range from $-ma$ to $+ma$ by $2$'s.  Given that the coefficient on $a$ is $n$, you must have had $\frac {m+n}2$ plus signs on $a$'s and $\frac {m-n}2$ minus signs.  The $b$'s can range from $n-m$ to $m+n$

Comment: Thanks so much! I have one question: can the b's range from $n-m$ to $m+n$ by 1's, or not always so?

Comment: The coefficient of $b$ can range from $n-m$ to $m+n$ by $1$'s.  You start with all $+2$'s, then change one to a $+1$, and so on.  When you run out of $+$'s, you start on the minus signs.